# What are the best practices for benchmarking different Java collections?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, java-7

I have couple interesting Java collections in my hand such as:

1. http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/
2. Java 7
3. Java 7 concurrent collections
4. Scala collections
5. Homegrown collections that we have at some company

I wonder what would be the best practices to test these API's, from a performance and scalability perspective, i.e. which one is fastest, most scalable, performant, etc.  Should I set with million(s) of random elements and use timer or something else?  Just wanted to satisfy my curiosity and see which one would win.

Comment: As with all benchmarking you must test the performance characteristics that you are interested in. A winner for one kind of usage might be a looser for another. So ask yourself: What characteristics do I consider important and measure them!

Comment: agree, also the convenience of utilizing one collection could outweigh the intention of shaving off couple of milliseconds for small subset of data.

Comment: But still, it is probably so that you can identify some general use cases for collection classes - like "fastest linked-list on non-synchronized inserts on 1 000 000 objects" and others. Such measurements would be pretty generic.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: JMH is better nowadays*

Check out [Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper). It will be having its 1.0 release this fall, but many people are already using it with good results (by building it from source; sorry).

Glance over some of the ScareText at https://github.com/google/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks, though.

Comment: Well, those are tools to aid writing benchmarks. The benchmarks are still missing. Although one of the examples is an array sort benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

[There's a white paper on somebody benchmarking Java collections](http://scrtchpad.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/java-collections-performance-evaluation.pdf). I didn't see any source code, though.

Comment: Without the code, I would treat that paper as completely 100% useless, personally.

Comment: Just send the guy an email. Maybe, with some nudging, he'll put the code on github.

Comment: Well, I found it useful from performance perspective, and especially if you want to do sampling.

Comment: The point is that we have no idea whether the methodology is sound.